# Gatsby: gatsby-plugin-theme-ui 'Tag is not defined' error

Tags: reactjs, themes, node-modules, gatsby, referenceerror

I'm very new to Gatsby and have a project bootstrapped with the `gatsby-ghost-starter` starter. The starter works just fine and now I'm attempting to install a theme for the blog section of the site.

I'm attempting to use [gatsby-theme-blog](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-theme-blog/) for the blog section. I've ran `npm install gatsby-theme-blog` in the root of my project and configured `gatsby-config` to contain:

```
`gatsby-plugin-theme-ui`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-theme-blog`,
      options: {
        // basePath defaults to `/`
        basePath: `/blog`,
      },
    },
```

Note: this is not my entire config file, the file is longer and I'm just showing what I added for the sake of installing this theme.

After installing the theme and configuring it in the config I ran `gatsby build` and got the following error:

[image]

The error is occurring in my `node_modules` file located at `node_modules/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/src/provider.js:1:1` and `node_modules/gatsby-plugin-theme-ui/gatsby-ssr.js:1:1`. I tried deleting the comment `/* @jsx jsx */` on line 1 and restarting the server. When I remove that comment and restart I get the same error on line 2.

What is causing this error? This is my first time trying to install a theme within an existing project, am I forgetting something?